# What is the problem in wubi.exe for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, 14.04, windows-7, wubi

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 LTS desktop version for my Windows 7 64-Bit machine as there was no separate link on ubuntu site for only wubi.exe.
The package had wubi.exe.
I executed wubi.exe and on completing download, an error occured for 'Permission denied.'.
I executed it as 'run as administrator', but even though, it is giving error again and again.

There is no problem in my machine as I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS many times on my computer using wubi.exe.

Please provide some possible solution.

Thanks in advance.